# VBA Concatenate 2 Columns

Tags: vba

How can I concatenate columns A and B to create column C?

```
A    B  
abc  jkl 
def  mno 
ghi  pqr
```

Column C should be this:

```
C
abc
def
ghi
jkl
mno
pqr
```

Comment: You mean to say to need to concatenate columns in excel?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is that what you are looking for**

```
Sub testing()
Dim lrow1 As Long
Dim lrow2 As Long

With ActiveSheet
lrow1 = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lrow2 = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

.Range("A1:A" & lrow1).Copy .Range("C1")
.Range("B1:B" & lrow2).Copy .Range("C" & lrow1 + 1)

End With

End Sub
```

i run this macro .got the below result

[image]